# Unneeded space in the Doxygen comments for PHP files in Vim

Tags: vim, doxygen, file-type

I am using [DoxygenToolkit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=987) Vim Script ([source code](https://github.com/vim-scripts/DoxygenToolkit.vim)) to auto generate Doxygen comments. It is working properly in cpp/h files. But the problem happens in PHP files.

The comments block look like

```
/**
    * 
    * @param pacm
    *
    * @return 
 */
```

instead of

```
/**
 * 
 *
 * @param pacm
 *
 * @return 
 */
```

This happens only for PHP files. I checked the different settings in the PHP and cpp file windows but couldn't figure out the reason.

The following are the different settings that I checked.

### `shiftwidth`

php - 4, cpp 4

### `comments`

cpp

`comments=sO:* -,mO:*  ,exO:*/,s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://`
        Last set from ~/Dropbox/code/dotfiles/vim/vim/bundle/DoxygenToolkit.vim/plugin/DoxygenToolkit.vim

php

`comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,:#`
        Last set from ~/Dropbox/code/dotfiles/vim/vim/bundle/DoxygenToolkit.vim/plugin/DoxygenToolkit.vim

I tried changing it to the options used by cpp, but that didn't change anything.

### `cindent`

cpp - cindent
php - nocindent - I modifyed it to cindent, but it didn't made any difference.

### `cinoptions`

Empty for both php and cpp files. However the DoxygenToolkit script used the option `c1C1`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are those "all combinations"?

Comment: What about `cinoptions`?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat and romainl I have updated the question with the options that I tried and their values.

Answer (score 1):

try simply change

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

to

```
filetype plugin on
```

in ~/.vimrc. if it works, your indent options might be updated in $DIR_OF_VIM/vim/vim80/indent/php.vim.(vim80 indicates my vim version)。

```
:verbose set autoindent?
```

tells the last time autoindent is updated. If it is updated in $DIR_OF_VIM/vim/vim80/indent/php.vim indeed. you need to update it in ~/.vim/after/indent/php.vim.

```
setlocal indentexpr=
setlocal cindent
```

and keep

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

in your ~/.vimrc.

good luck.